# Global variables in web2py controllers

Tags: web2py

I am want to use global variables in web2py controller but as I have found, controllers is loaded in every request. So my global variable is accessible everywhere but read-only. Changes are not reflected accross sessions/requests.

Is is possible to define globals somewhere? I tried to put global object in controller, i have also tried to put it to model/db.py.

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/web2py@googlegroups.com/msg30072.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the database. For example you could create a settings table:

```
db.define_table('settings,
    Field('max_size', 'integer', default=10),
    Field('summary', 'text', 'abc'),
    ...
)
# create an instance of settings table
settings = db(db.settings.id > 0).select().first()
if not settings:
    settings = db.settings.insert()
```

And then access it with:

```
settings.max_size # get the value
settings.update_record(summary=new_summary) # set a value
```

Comment: I should give it a try. I thought about not using database at all, but as I understand now, because of architecture that enables scaling etc it is nescessary to avoid global variables. I have started working on object that encapsulates db table access with update+commit after setattr.